# KiwiIRC installing side by side with IIS

Tags: node.js, iis

I'm trying to configure KiwiIRC side by side with IIS.
I am trying to have kiwi irc listening on port 80, but I also need IIS server. I don't see a way to configure this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ran into the same issue. So far I've found installing official node.js executable and then installing [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), but I could not get KiwiIRC to work yet.

Comment: yep, I gave up on kiwiIRC.